# Trying to store google maps geocode location as a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API3 to place a marker on the Google Map based on Longitude and Latitude coordinates, with reverse Geocoding.

Based on the lat and lng, the maps finds an adress and presents it just fine. However, i need to send that specific address back to the php-side of things. And I just dont know how? I've tried to use Ajax-request but I guess I'm just doing it wrong.

This is what the function looks like (.js):

```
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) 
{   
    result.forEach(function(entry) {
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(entry.lat), lng: parseFloat(entry.lng)};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                if (results[1])
                {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map
                        });
                    infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                    // send som data
                    var xhttp;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    var PageToSendTo = "article.php?";
                    var markerLocation = results[1].formatted_address;
                    var VariablePlaceholder = "location=";
                    var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + markerLocation;
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, false);
                    xmlhttp.send();

                } 
                else 
                {
                    window.alert('No results found');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

**var markerLocation** contains the data I need to store in a PHP-variable, but I dont know how to get it across (from the js to the php) correctly.

And this is the serverside php file (article.php):

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'src/articleLogic.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=$id";
$result = db_select($sql);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable
var result = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map_article.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myAPIkey&callback=initMap"></script>
<body>

<?php echo $navbar; ?>

<div id="map">
</div>

<?php getArticle(); ?>

<div id="photos">
<?php getFlickrPhotos(); ?>
</div>

<?php 
// Testing the jquery get-method
if(isset($_GET['location']))
    {
        echo $_GET['location']; 
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "It didnt work";
    }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit: Code has been updated with the faulty ajaxrequest.**

Comment: Can we see the AJAX request that you tried? I'm suer we can help you sort this all out if we can see where you went wrong with that.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I've added my attempt for the AJAX request in the function. Under the comment // Send some data.

And this is what the console tells me:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery get function. You need jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and place following code right after you create `markerLocation` variable:

```
$.get('your.php?location='+markerLocation, function(data){
  //what to do on success
});
```

Then in PHP script the value will be in `$_GET['location']`.

Comment: Added that, and tried to echo $_GET['location'] on the php-side... but it is still undefined. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Stim your client-side script looks ok. can you post your php script?